# Icinga2 dependecies of devices on HA

Tags: monitoring, high-availability, icinga, system-monitoring

I would like to configure a Host-to-Host dependency on Icinga2, however, one of the Hosts has an HA configuration, so I need the to trigger it only when both HA devices are down. Suppose this scenario:

[image]

Let's say I have all these devices on Icinga2. It's clear that WAN switch has a dependency on both routers, so I want to avoid monitoring the WAN switch only if BOTH routers are down. I could not find anything like this on Icinga2 docs. Anybody has an idea of the best way to set this?

Comment: Write your own script?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has been fixed in 2.3.10, so multiple host dependencies can exist. (https://dev.icinga.org/issues/10058)

There is a whole chapter in the docs: 
http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/monitoring-basics#dependencies

What you basically do two dependencies:

```
apply Dependency "behind-rtr1" to Host {
  parent_host_name = "rtr1"
  disable_checks = true
  disable_notifications = true

  // how ever you would specify that
  assign where host.vars.zone == "wan"
}
apply Dependency "behind-rtr2" to Host {
  parent_host_name = "rtr2"
  disable_checks = true
  disable_notifications = true

  // how ever you would specify that
  assign where host.vars.zone == "wan"
}
```

Comment: OP is requesting a logical 'and' between multiple dependencies which is discussed here: https://dev.icinga.org/issues/6871